# Modeling logical expressions of entities in a database

Tags: database-design, relational-database, data-modeling, logical-operators

I have a database table `X` with entities:

| idX | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | example 1 |
| ... | example .. |
| n | example n |

I want to allow my customers to create different logical expression based on the entities of `X`. For example having the primary keys 1,2,3,4 they should be able to create the expression: `(1 OR 2) AND (3 OR 4)` with a GUI. This expression can later be used to validate some logic.

Therefore I created a table `Operator` that contains logical operators like `AND`, `OR`:

| idOperator | Operator |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | & (AND) |
| 2 | | (OR) |

Table `XLogic`:

| idXLogic | idX (nullable) | idOperator (nullable) | idXLogicLeft (nullable) | idXLogicRight (nullable) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

Using this table I could add the example from above:

| idXLogic | idX (nullable) | idOperator (nullable) | idXLogicLeft (nullable) | idXLogicRight (nullable) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | null | null | null |
| 2 | 2 | null | null | null |
| 3 | 3 | null | null | null |
| 4 | 4 | null | null | null |
| 5 | null | 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 6 | null | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 7 | null | 1 | 5 | 6 |

The row with idXLogic=7 represents the logical expression: `(idX=1 OR idX=2) AND (idX=3 OR idX=4)`. Is this a good idea to represent such logical expressions based or are there better ways?

Answer (score 0):

Modelling a logical expression using tables for the elements is a very complex way of doing it. Expressions could involve parentheses which contain sub-expressions and you have to be cognizant of the order of expression elements.  To have a fully flexible expression persistence mechanism based on storing elements in a third-normal-form set of relational tables you are setting yourself up for a lot of complexity.

There are libraries available that will do expression evaluation based on storing the expression as a string, with perhaps some tokens within the expression being replaced at runtime with variable values or functions that evaluate to a value.  If you use a library like this then you can store your expression as a single string.  You would probably want to use the library's lexer feature (if it has one) to confirm the syntax is valid.

The only good reason that I could think of for keeping an expression in a normalized database would be because you need to do some reporting or analysis on which expression elements are being used where.  Even in a situation like this, though, you could store the expression itself as a string and keep a comparatively simple set of tables (possibly as simple as a single intersection table) that records which expression elements are used in which expressions.